# Stata - panel data graphs hiding/selecting observations with "direct" labelling

Tags: graph, panel, stata

I have a panel data set with id = 1,..,10 and time = -30,...,30. I would like to draw a line graph in which only the id = 1, 10 appears, or in other words I would like to hide the other observations.

Using the graph editor I could hide those observations I do not want to see, but as I have a lot of these graphs I would like to use a command for the *.do-file.

Moreover, instead of the legend in the graph I would like to have Stata draw a little line and assign the label directly to the line.

Another issues are regarding the "design" of the graph: Could you recommend a webpage or so in which I can find out more about that? (i.e. horizontal y-axis-labelling, defining max-min range plus ticks etc. pp).

Comment: Please post the code you've been trying and why it's not working for you. A complete, working example, is even better. Posts only requesting code are deemed off-topic by many users answering questions.

Comment: Your question about the "design" is very general. Have you checked `help twoway options`?

Comment: Sorry my comment came across as very unhelpful. I think the examples with `help axis_options` should cover the issues you mentioned. If you prefer a tutorial, UCLA has some [learning modules](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/STAT/stata/modules/) that may be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting @DimitriyV.Masterov:

> There's no way to label individual lines (unless you do it by hand using the graph editor).

I'll take that challenge. Here is an example on how to label the lines without the graph editor:

```
webuse nlswork, clear

foreach var of varlist ln_wage hours { 
    separate `var' if inlist(idcode,1,10), by(idcode) gen(obs_)
    gen byte miss = missing(`var')
    bys miss idcode (year) : gen labx = year ///
        if _n == _N & miss == 0 & inlist(idcode,1,10)
    gen laby = `var' if !missing(labx)
    tw line obs_* year  || ///
        scatter laby labx, msymbol(i) mlabel(idcode) mlabpos(3) ///
        name(`var', replace) legend(off)
    drop obs_* miss labx laby
}
```

Comment: also check out -sparkline- from SSC.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two examples of how to do this for several variables, assuming you have the data in the usual long panel format:

```
webuse nlswork, clear

foreach var of varlist ln_wage hours { 

    /* Each panel in its own plot of outcome against time */ 
    xtline `var' if inlist(idcode,1,10), ylabel(#15,angle(horizontal)) xlabel(68(10)88)

    /* Put both panels in the same plot */  
    separate `var' if inlist(idcode,1,10), by(idcode) gen(obs_)
    tw line obs_* year  
    drop obs_*      
}
```

There's no way to label individual lines (unless you do it by hand using the graph editor).

A wonderful intro to Stata graphics is [Michael Mitchell's book](http://www.michaelnormanmitchell.com/vgsg/). There is also the [pdf graphics manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/g.pdf), which has lots of examples. None of the [web resources](http://www.survey-design.com.au/Stata%20Graphs.html) that I am aware of come close.